# How to pass java script parameter string values in single quotes from c#

Tags: javascript

C# Code

```
string excerpt = "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' onclick='javascript:onOptionSelect(" + pat.PatientId + "," + pat.PatientName.Replace(",", "") + "," + pat.PatientDob + ",1" + ")'>Patient Chart</a>";
```

I need to pass the string values pat.PatientName and pat.PatientDob in single quotes to java script function. I tried many ways but i am not able to find out the right way of passing values.

Comment: Just add single quotes to your string: `...'" + pat.PatientDob + "'...`. Also, drop the `javascript:`, it's unnecessary there and if you can use another way to bind event handlers.

Comment: try to escape the single quotes with a back slash. use(\'), it should pass the single quote in that case.

Comment: I am writing this code in c# and i am assigning the html as a value to column of a grid in extjs.

Comment: I have added single quotes but it renders as

<a href="#" onclick="onOptionSelect(61385,AADITYA VIJJU," 11="" 29="" 1974',1)'="">Patient Chart</a>

Comment: Oh, now I see... you also use single quotes for the HTML attribute values. Use double quotes instead (and escape them) or use double quotes for the function arguments (and escape them).